# How to input a text file into an exe through cmd?

Tags: c

Trying to use my program to take a `stdin` through the `cmd`.

For example, I have a program that takes in a number from user input using scanf.

How do I use the console to redirect the input.

I've tried `program.exe < input.txt`, but I get an error that the file specified is not found.

When I run the exe and type `<input.txt`, it outputs a single line of what I assume to be a memory address.

edit:
Figured out the input, however getting an unexpected output.

```
 #define SIZE 5
    int main(){

    int i,j,num, row[SIZE];
    char line[SIZE+1];


    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("%d", num);

    for(i=0;i<num;i++){

        scanf("%s", line);

        for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)

             arr[i] = line[i] - '0';

        printf("%d",arr);
```

What it's meant to do is take in a number of lines to variable num.

From there, it should can the all lines and take a string of numbers, then put that string of numbers into an array of int.

E.g. input

1
28374

e.g. output

28374

Which should really be

> arr[0]=2,
>    arr[1]=8, 
>    arr[2]=3,
>   and so on

.

Comment: `program.exe < input.txt` should work. Are you sure that the file is there? And show your code so we can help you because right now there's nothing we can say...

Comment: program.exe < input.txt does work. For some reason when I was creating the file an extra extension was added to the end. However, I'm still having the same issue with it printing what looks like an address. I'll post the code in a sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Using command line argument pass file name to your c program. study this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm

2) 
then in your c program open that file and read input.

Comment: I've gotten the input to work, but still having an issue with the output. Edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

It goes like this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 256

int main ()
{
    int16_t i;                                                                                                                                                         
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    while (NULL != fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)) {
        sscanf(buffer, "%[^\n]", buffer);

        uint8_t len = strlen(buffer);
        uint8_t numbers[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            numbers[len - 1 - i] = buffer[i] - '0';
        }

        bool high = false;
        for (i = BUFFER_SIZE - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            high = high || (0 != numbers[i]);

            if (high) {
                printf("[%d] => %d\t", i, numbers[i]);
            }
        }

        putchar('\n');
    }   

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

content of input `numbers.txt`:

```
54673
1245841
326987
```

Then you can run your program like this:

```
./app < numbers.txt
```